# Does processModel/serverErrorMessageFile work when accidentally mixing ASP.NET versions in IIS6?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6, custom-error-pages, custom-errors

I've tried setting `serverErrorMessageFile` to a path relative to machine.config, and to an absolute path, but when accessing an app on our IIS6 server that shares a pool with another ASP.NET version, we still get the big, ugly, red, *default* **Server Application Unavailable** message.

Since one of our ASP.NET apps recently (and mysteriously) changed app pools to one occupied by an app with a different ASP.NET version, *again* (we have yet to determine the cause--patches, third party software, too many admins), we'd like to be able to customize that error so that users see something a bit less alarming and useless if this happens again, for whatever reason.

So, does `serverErrorMessageFile` not work in IIS6, or does it not work for ASP.NET version conflicts, or have I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.processmodelsection.servererrormessagefile%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that the attribute is supported on .NET Framework versions 2 & 3.  Perhaps it's a 1.x app pool that's getting polluted and therefore triggering the exception.  What versions of the framework are at play here?

Comment: It would've been .NET 1.1 vs. .NET 2.0/3.5 IIRC. Luckily, this hasn't been something we've had trouble with lately.